# Как в виджете Android при нажатии выполнить код

Tags: android

Как при нажатии на свой виджет выполнить определенный код?

Виджет из себя представляет всего 1 картинку, при нажатии на которую выполнится определенный код, вызывать Activity не нужно.

Comment: о каком виджете идет речь - виджет рабочего экрана (App Widget ) или виджет приложения, как Button, TextView

Comment: @pavlofff виджет рабочего экрана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработка нажатий на виджет выполняется через `PendingIntent'ы`.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".widget.Widget"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        <action android:name="ru.ztrap.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        <action android:name="ru.ztrap.STOP_WIDGET_ANIMATION"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
</receiver>
```

### Widget.java

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public final static String STOP_WIDGET_ANIMATION = "ru.ztrap.STOP_WIDGET_ANIMATION";
    public final static String FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE = "ru.ztrap.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
            updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, id);
        }    
    }

    //вызывается каждый раз, при отлове broadcast'a с установленным для виджета фильтром
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        //Проверка action и при соответствии - выполнение вашего кода
        if (FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int widgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            int[] allWidgetIds = { widgetID };
            Intent i = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
            i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
            context.startService(i);
        }
        if (STOP_WIDGET_ANIMATION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // обновляете виджет после обновления данных
        }
    }

    private void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetID) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
        updateIntent.setAction(FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE);
        updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID); // id виджета, который от которого будет послан broadcast
        int[] allWidgetIds = {widgetID}; // id виджетов, которые необходимо будет обновить
        updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetID, updateIntent, 0); // создаём PendingIntent который будет отправляться при нажатии
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pIntent); // id кнопки, по нажатию на которую будет отправлен broadcast
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, views);
    }
}
```

### YourService.java

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {

    public YourService() {
        super("YourService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Widget.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        Integer[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        if (allWidgetIds == null)
            allWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;
        for (int widgetID : allWidgetIds) {
            // здесь делаете то, что вам нужно, после чего отправляете broadcast (если после этих действий вам нужно обновить виджет)
            Intent i = new Intent(Widget.STOP_WIDGET_ANIMATION);
            i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }
}
```